# OpenCV: Match an unknown object (but different from background) near a coordinate

Tags: python, c++, opencv, graphics, computer-vision

I have an image, whose background is pure color, so I can remove the background easily.

And here's the problem:

I know there is an object (say *Object A*) near a coordinate(the coordinate is the on the edge of this object), and I know *Object A* is one of the known objects, but **don't know which one**.

So how could I match this *Object A* to a known object, via OpenCV?

Comment: could you show the background removed image?

Comment: Do you have rotations or scaling of the object inside the image or is it quite the same as the ones you already know?